# What does import unquote(__MODULE__) do in a using callback?

Tags: elixir

In the following code:

```
defmodule ModuleToBeUsed do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      import unquote(__MODULE__)
    end
  end
end

defmodule ModuleUsing do
  use ModuleToBeUsed
end
```

What does the line `import unquote(__MODULE__)` do? `__MODULE__` refers to `ModuleUsing`. Is it importing it into itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elixir (as well as erlang) has *two* stages of “execution.” The code is being “executed” during a compilation stage to produce the beam; afterwards the code is executing on the “execution” stage (I know this sounds a bit cumbersome, but the code below would help to understand what’s going on.)

Consider the following code:

```
$ cat /tmp/test.ex

defmodule ModuleToBeUsed do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    IO.puts __MODULE__ # COMPILATION STAGE
    quote do # needed to prevent execution on compilation stage
      import unquote(__MODULE__)
      def test, do: IO.puts "I am test" # EXECUTION STAGE
    end
  end
end

defmodule ModuleUsing do
  use ModuleToBeUsed

  def test_of_test, do: test() # I can call `test` here!
end

ModuleUsing.test_of_test()
```

The code above will output

```
Elixir.ModuleToBeUsed # from compilation stage
I am test             # on execution stage
```

Remove the last actual call to `ModuleUsing.test_of_test()` and you’ll still see the first output (with module name.)

---

Now turning back to your question. `quote do: import unquote(__MODULE__)` inside a macro would compile to `import` (as is) `ModuleToBeUsed` (due to `unquote`, it would be expanded *on compilation stage*.) On execution stage that would force `ModuleUsing` to import `ModuleToBeUsed`. making a call to `test()` possible without a namespace (otherwise one should be calling it as `ModuleToBeUsed.test()`.

Comment: That explains it. Thanks for replying even though my example code was wrong. I did mean to ask regarding `quote do: import unquote(__MODULE__)`. I have updated my question with correct code.

Comment: You are always welcome; the typo did not make the question unclear and I myself spent a noticable amount of time wrapping my head around these two stages.

Answer (score 1):

At that point in your code `__MODULE__` refers to `ModuleToBeUsed`. And this code won't compile because it creates a circular dependency.